# Is there a away to calculate when an id in a dataframe has the same value in another field?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Forgive me for a possible stupid question:
I'm working with a dataset like below:

```
day id reviewer flag
1   1  bill     agree
1   1  sarah    disagree
1   1  scott    disagree
1   1  jon      agree
2   2  bill     agree
2   2  sarah    agree
2   2  scott    agree
2   2  jon      agree 
3   3  jon      disagree
3   3  bill     disagree
3   3  sarah    disagree
3   3  scott    disagree
```

In Python I'm trying to derive what overall % of time the reviewers apply the same flag for a given id across all days. In the example above it should be 66% as only twice once did all reviewers align (all disagree or all agreed

I'm stuck on how best to approach (`for` loop? a derived calculation?, etc).

i started off trying to derive like some such
df['flag'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100/df['id'].value_counts

Comment: Please provide more info. What is the formula you are using? What is the expected output after applying the function?

Comment: Continuing what @drum said, would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Also, how is your data stored?  E.g., are you using pandas?

Comment: sorry i wasn't more clear. i'm using pandas and I want to just get the final % of overall alignment.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a combination of `groupby` and `for` loop. Which will look something like that:

```
groups = df.groupby("id")
matches = 0
for i, group in groups:
    if len(group) == len(group[group["flag"] == "agree"]) or \
       len(group) == len(group[group["flag"] == "disagree"]):
        matches += 1

per = matches/len(groups) * 100
print("Agree ratio is {:.3f}%".format(per))
# Agree ratio is 66.667%
```

Comment: thank you @Anwarvic.  see my change to the data set. if 'alignment' is any time all reviewers have the same flag (all agree or all disagree) did i capture the grouping right below?

`groups = df.groupby("id")
matches = 0
for i, group in groups:
    if len(group) == len(group[group["flag"] == "approve"]):
        matches += 1
    elif len(group) == len(group[group["flag"] == "disapprove"]):
        matches += 1

per = matches/len(groups) * 100
print("Aligned ratio is {:.3f}%".format(per))`

Comment: yes, this will work. But you should notice that it's `agree` not `approve` and `disagree` not  `disapprove`. I even edited my answer with the question update